# what is silverlight developer runtime ? and why we need it?

Tags: silverlight

I want to know more in detail about th developer runtime of silverlight

what is silverlight developer runtime ? and why we need it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The developer runtime is a special debugging version of the browser Silverlight plugin. It replaces the release version you would normally install in your browser.

You need it so Visual Studio can debug your Silverlight applications.

*Please note that occasionally Silverlight prompts for upgrades. You **must not** upgrade via a web browser or you will replace your developer runtime with the retail/release version. You want to look for a more recent developer runtime release instead*

Answer (score 0):

The developer runtime is needed to be able to debug the Silverlight applications using Visual Studio.